# Adding An Object Onto ArrayList Between Two Classes

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to add order1 object to orderList in the Customer class, but it's not working. The `toString()` method returns zero items in the ArrayList. Does anyone have any idea of what else I can try doing instead?

```
public class Customer {
       private ArrayList<Order> orderList;
       private int numberOfOrders = 0;

       public Customer(String name, Order firstElementInList) {
               this(name);
               this.orderList.add(0, firstElementInList);
       }

       public void setNumberOfOrders() {
           this.numberOfOrders = orderList.size();
       }

       public String toString() {
           return name + numberOfOrders;
       }
}

public class Main {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Order order1 = new Order( "bob", 1.1 );
        Customer bob = new Customer( "Bobby Shmurda ", order1 );


        System.out.println(bob.toString());
    }
}
```

A String Object gets added to ArrayList and when `toString()` is invoked should return the length of the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Because your list is yet to be created as you have not created its object.

Use below code to create your list.

```
private ArrayList<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Customer {
   private List<Order> orderList;
   private int numberOfOrders = 0;

   public Customer(String name, Order firstElementInList) {
           this(name);
           if(orderList == null) {
                orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
           }
           this.orderList.add(0, firstElementInList);
   }

   public void setNumberOfOrders() {
       this.numberOfOrders = orderList.size();
   }

   public String toString() {
       return "The length of the orderList: " + orderList != null ? orderList.size() : 0;
   }
}
public class Main {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Order order1 = new Order( "bob", 1.1 );
        Customer bob = new Customer( "Bobby Shmurda ", order1 );


        System.out.println(bob.toString());
    }
}
```